# Problems with C++ containers

Tags: c++, list, memory-management, stl, containers

I have a std::list in a C++ program, which contains objects of a Class A. 
Lets say I have 10 objects in it. I have a reference to the 6th object stored, in another data structure say ref_6. Lets say I need to remove the 8th element from my list. To do this, I would use pop_front 8 times and store 8 objects in a vector and use push_front 7 times to insert the first 7 elements back in the list so now my resulting list would have 9 elemnts. Now i when i try to access the object stored in ref_6 , which was the 6th element , I cant do it. There is some garbage value in this reference.
I am assuming that when i do a pop and a push, the memory location of the same object changes . How do I deal with this ?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you erase things in such a manner? D: It's not a stack. The entire point (and *only* point*) of a list is that you can remove any element in constant time. (Though finding it is linear.)

Just do this:

```
typedef std::list<T> list_type;

list_type mylist; // populate it

list_type::iterator iter =  mylist.begin();
std::advance(iter, 8); // move to 8th item

mylist.erase(iter); // erase it
```

And no other iterators are invalidated. (Indeed, erasing an element invalidates any references to it.)

---

*You probably shouldn't even be using a list. Lists are nice when it comes to learning data structures, but they're pretty awful.

Comment: So this way , the list size (memory start and memory end locations) remains as is , its just that one element is removed/invalidated. isnt it ?

Comment: I am curious of your comments on list usage in real life ---- It is in STL for its reasons, as you said: insert or remove any element in constant time

Comment: @cyrux: Yes, the linked list will remove that element only, the others are valid. @Dbger: The standard library includes it because it's such a common data structure, and because it does have its uses. But those uses are few; your main operation would basically be iterating through the container and removing elements frequently, and doing *that* frequently. The terrible cache-coherence it has along with linear access times make it very slow in practice; even if you erase something from the middle semi-often, a `vector`/`deque` will perform better because of locality.

Comment: "list...they're pretty awful". I dunno. I find the guarantees std::list makes w.r.t. iterator validity, O(1) complexities etc pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

The list stores its elements in discontinous chunks of memory that get freed when the element is removed from the list. So the reference ( which is implemented simply as a pointer ) points to an element whose memory has been already freed.

Easier way to remove a given element from the list is to get the iterator pointing to it and use method

`std::list::iterator =  /*somehow get the iterator to the 8th element*/ 

yourList.erase(8th_element_iterator);`

The first step ( getting the iterator to the 8th element ) can be done for example by getting the iterator of the begininning of the list and advancing it 7 positions forward:

`std::list::iterator first_iter = yourList.begin(); 

std::list::iterator 8th_iter = std::advance(first_iter, 7);`

Answer (score 0):

Something smells fishy here... You are storing object of type `T` in a `std::list<T>` by value. You keep references to those objects in other places. Is that correct? If yes, I see several problems... Many manipulations of lists might invalidate stored references, since `std::list<T>` only guarantees a sequential order of **values** of elements of type `T`. If you want to store references to those elements in several places use `std::tr1::shared_ptr<T>` and `std::list<std::shared_ptr<T> >`. Then, you can safely remove or add (even reposition) elements in your list and the references kept in other places remain valid. Beware of storing `std::list<T>iterators`, the problem would be the same.

Comment: you say that I am holding object of type T by value, but in the stl_list the push_front has this prototype void push_front(const value_type& __x). So isnt this holding reference, is this same as value. Also, in the other place when i said i hold reference, i was actually using pointers and that i believe was causing the problem. So you say that if I used list of shared_ptr , then I can remove and add elements and my references to these elements would work fine. Does this hold if I change the ordering of elements in list, like use pop_front to get element and then push_back ?

Answer (score 0):

I am referring to your response. Sorry, I didn't get the account thing right...
Please consider the following:

```
std::list<A> tList;
A tA;

tList.push_back(tA);
assert(&tA == &tList.back()); // boom!

A *tAPtr = &tList.front();

tList.erase(tList.front());
// try to access tAPtr:
tAPtr->Foo(); // boom! (probably)
```

The point is that instances of `A` are stored by value (= copied), so what you are doing is inherently unsafe. Use `std::list<std::tr1::shared_ptr<A> >` instead!